# Replacing dashes for guessed letters in my hangman game VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble switching my dashes to guessed letters on my hangman game. Below is what I have, but it does not work.

```
lblWord = ""
LengthofWord = Len(EnterWord) - 1
For iLetter = 0 To LengthofWord
lblWord = lblWord & "____ "


Next


End Sub

Sub GuessLetter(stGuess As String)
LengthofWord = Len(EnterWord) - 1
lblWord = ""

Dim stGuess As String

stGuess = Me.txtGuess.Text

If Mid(EnterWord, iLetter, 1) = stGuess Then
bFound = True
If bFound = True Then
  Me.lblWord.Caption = stGuess
    Else
    Me.lblWord.Caption = lblWord & lblWord(iLetter, 1)
    End If

    Next
    lblWord = lblWord
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the desire output? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Hangman is really a great game for studying any type of programming. Here is something to start with:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim secretWord          As String
    Dim currentResult       As String

    secretWord = "stackoverflow"
    currentResult = "__a__o_____o_"

    currentResult = TryToHang(secretWord, "s", currentResult)
    currentResult = TryToHang(secretWord, "t", currentResult)
    currentResult = TryToHang(secretWord, "c", currentResult)

    Debug.Print currentResult

End Sub

Public Function TryToHang(secretWord, guess, currentResult) As String

    Dim cnt             As Long

    For cnt = 1 To Len(secretWord)
        If Mid(secretWord, cnt, 1) = guess Then
            Mid(currentResult, cnt, 1) = guess
        End If
    Next cnt

    TryToHang = currentResult

End Function
```

After running the `TestMe()`, you would get `stac_o_____o_` on the console. As next steps, make some string builder, that generates the initial current result string as long as the given word - `__________`.

And probably rewrite everything in a `While(True)` Loop, asking for input until the hangman is complete.